# Spring Application 404 for css file but not for html file

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Solution: The SpringWebConfig class wasn't being picked up because it was in a different package than the application. Once I got them together and tweaked the paths a bit, everything worked as intended. Followed a bad guide on the package setup. Thanks for your help everyone!

I have a spring application that I'm trying to configure with annotation. On localhost when testing, spring returns html pages in src/main/resources/templates fine, but nothing I specify in my config.java file is respected. I also can't get the browser to load any css files in src/main/resources/static. I've never been able to get this thing to resolve anything in WEB-INF.

I've read about a hundred guides on annotation config, xml config, and I've reconfigured this about a dozen times today. There are a ton of threads on here as well, but nothing has worked. It's like none of my changes in my webconfig.java are being called at all.

The path setup is css files in src/main/resources/static, and html in src/main/resources/templates.

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

Spring web config:

```
@EnableWebMvc // mvc:annotation-driven
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"config"})
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("static/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/static/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        System.out.println("test");
        return viewResolver;
    }


    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
      configurer.enable("WebInitializer"); 
    }

}
```

Servlet initializer:

```
public class WebInitializer {

    public class MyWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return new Class[] {SpringWebConfig.class};
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[] {"/"};
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

replaytemplate.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"></meta>
<title>$title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css" type="text/css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="#Patreon">Patreon</a> <a href="#Stats">Stats</a>
        <a href="#Ladder">Ladder</a> <a href="#Tournaments">Tournaments</a> <a
            href="#Adv. Search">Adv. Search</a> <a href="#Forum">Forum</a> <a
            href="#Wiki">Wiki</a>
</div>
<ul>
    <li>$ReplayID</li>
    <li>$TimePlayed</li>
    <li>$TimeUploaded</li>
    <li>$GameLength</li>
    <li>$Map</li>
    <li>$P1URL</li>
    <li>$P1Race</li>
    <li>$P2URL</li>
    <li>$P2Race</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I can resolve this webpage, but chrome 404's on the css file. I'm having similar results with upload.html, and dropzone.css.

I just want to be able to understand what's going on, and why, and there don't seem to be any guides I can find that explain why springwebconfig.java isn't being referenced, or where I'm meant to put any of the html or css files. I've seen a ton of guides on WEB-INF stuff, but I can never seem to get references to those to resolve. Am I meant to have some xml config in addition to this? The setup I have now resolves upload.html fine, but in chrome I get a 404 when referencing the css files.

TL;DR Nothing about SpringWebConfig seems to work with respect to the viewresolver. I have to move html files into src/main/resources/templates to resolve, and when that happens I get a 404 on the css file, no matter what I change the href to, it seems. Sometimes when I change the href (I think I get it right sometimes) nothing displays in the eclipse console, it just doesn't apply the css, and gives a 404 in chrome for the css file. Other times I get a template resolution error in eclipse, and the 404 in chrome.

Edit: pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>continuum</groupId>
        <artifactId>Continuum</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>
        <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>scelight</groupId>
                        <artifactId>Scelight</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                        <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
                        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <properties>
                <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>
        <build>
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>2.6</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                </plugins>
        </build>
        <repositories>
                <repository>
                        <id>spring-milestone</id>
                        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
                </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                        <id>spring-milestone</id>
                        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
                </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just wrong, because you don't take the context into account. Please check http://server/context/static/main.css instead.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/, you don't need to configure the resolver

Comment: This is one of the things I started with. It doesn't seem to matter if I configure the resolver or not, the custom resolver code never runs.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to css stylesheet seems to be wrong. I see you are using thymeleaf so you could do something like below to link your css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/main.css}"/>
```

The static directory is served from /. So your `src/main/resources/static/main.css` will be served from `/main.css`. The above could also be written as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/main.css"/>
```

I see you have used `@EnableWebMvc` in your application which will disable Spring Boot's auto-configuration of Spring MVC

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/main.css}"/> Doesn't work, still gives a 404 on the main.css, with spring exception, so no change. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/main.css"/> This removes the spring exception, but I still get a 404 in chrome. Progress?

Comment: I see you have used @EnableWebMvc in your application which will disable Spring Boot's auto-configuration of Spring MVC Can you elaborate on this? Is this what should be triggering Spring to look at my custom annotation config, but isn't working?

Comment: Also, could this be context path related? I'm specifying a context path in application.properties.

Comment: you mean you have defined `server.servlet-path=<SOME_VALUE>` ?

Comment: I've got server.context-path=/Continuum in application.properties